# storing multiple thumbnails vs using css

Tags: css, performance, caching, browser, thumbnails

I'm working on a site that currently stores thumbnails of size 100x100.  A designer is working with us and has created a design which requires thumbnails of 100x100, 32x32, 22x22 and 16x16.

It is likely any given page on the site will be displaying the same thumbnail many times at different sizes.

My question is: Should we create and store thumbnails of each size?  Or is it enough to store the thumbnail as 100x100 and just use CSS to achieve the smaller thumbnail sizes?

My theory is that using the 100x100 thumbnail across the board and using CSS to get the desired size will perform better (ie: faster page loads) than storing each individual size.

Why do I think this?

Because the first time the 100x100 is downloaded it will be cached and the CSS will 'resize' it throughout the page where the same image is used.  If we store and reference differently image files explicitly we'll need to grab 4 files instead of just one and won't be able to leverage the browser's cache as well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't always guarantee that the end browser is going to cache the page. Especially on mobile devices, memory is very limited and so caches get filled up and invalidate quickly.

If you want fast page load times, you will want to make the smaller images since they will download faster. The only problem is request times. People browsing through things (such as a gallery of images) are going to skim through and only click on a few of the images. If you start out with all small thumbnails, the page would load pretty fast and then as they ask to increase the size of selected ones, you would dynamically load those images.

One thing you could do to reduce requests is use a server side script to put all the thumbnails of each size into a tileset of sorts (sorted by size...you could also do this manually if it were for a static page) and use CSS to adjust the view boundaries. This is how JQuery does their buttons. This would make it so that you would only have to request one image to load all the thumbnails for a given set. As your end user asks to increase the size of the thumbnails, your page could then dynamically request the larger sizes. The downside to this is that if you have many images on each page, you would have one big image to download and I believe that with many browsers, the users wouldn't see the image until it was fully loaded. Using individual thumbnails, they could see them progressing.

Comment: That's a good point about the cache.  Also good recommendation of reducing requests.